# do packages installed (without --name ) after conda environment activation affect outside?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I want to know after creating and activating a conda environment in terminal. Say `venv`:

```
conda create -n venv
source activate venv
```

Then the prompt will come with the enviroment name `(venv)`.
**would the packages installed   (say `conda install tensorflow` without `--name venv`)** **after environment activation only effect inside the environment `venv`**? Or **would it affect outside `venv`**?
I don't want to mess up my environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of using an environment in conda is to have a separate space where you can install packages and apply your configurations.

As long as you are inside an environment, all the packages you install will only be installed there. One way you can check this is by listing the packages you installed using:    `conda list`

You will see that the packages you installed in the active environment are not installed in the other ones.

I hope this answers your question

Comment: My doubt is, then **what's the point of `--name 'env_name'` argument when installing packages??** I've seen in so many places eg: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: That allows you to install a package in an environment without activating it (from the root environment). After you activate your environment, you don't enter the --name parameter.